# Keep track of location in an array of structs in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

For this assignment I'm using heaps to build a priority queue, sorted from lowest priority to highest. I created a structure which has two members, value and priority. In order to correctly locate each node's children, I need to keep track of its location. I originally had a third element in the struct, location, which was just set equal to heap_size, since nodes are added at the end of the array.

```
    heaptype Heap::getleft (heaptype *A, heaptype& node)
    {
            heaptype lchild;
            lchild.location = 2*node.location;

            for(int i =0 ; i <heapsize; i++)
            {
                    if(A[i].location == lchild.location)
                    {
                            lchild=A[i];
                    }
            return lchild;
            }

    void Heap::heapifyup(heaptype *A, heaptype &node)
    {
            heaptype min;
            heaptype r = getright(A, node);
            heaptype l = getleft(A, node);

            if(l.location<=heapsize && l.priority<node.priority)
            {
                    min = l;
            }

            else
            {
                    min = node;
            }

            if(r.location<=heapsize && r.priority<l.priority)
            {
                    min = r;
            }

            if(min.priority!=node.priority)
            {
                    swap(min, node);
                    heapifyup(A, min);
            }

    }

    void Heap::swap (heaptype& a, heaptype& b)
    {
            heaptype temp;
            temp.id = a.id;
            a.id = b.id;
            b.id = temp.id;
            temp.priority = a.priority;
            a.priority = b.priority;
            b.priority = temp.priority;
    }
```

This program will correctly swap the id and priority of the nodes I send to it, but after I call the swap function the array I'm working with will assign both nodes to the value and priority of whatever the lowest priority node was. 
Is there a way to fix the program I have now, or is there a more efficient way to keep track of the location of the nodes?

Comment: If this is homework you might want to say so, because otherwise the answer is probably going to be "use [`priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)".

Comment: Oh thanks, this is for homework. I edited it.

Comment: Wait... is the problem maintaining a `location` field in `node`, or swapping two nodes in an array without messing up their `value` and `priority` fields?